# div element management under skew limits

Tags: html, css

Ok then. I've a skewed button, with a div inside that is de-skewed to make images and text inside not looking like the leaning tower. Now I need inside that button to have a picture in the first 25% of the button, a text in the middle 50% and another image in the last 25%. I've tried with different divs but i had an issue depending on the fact that i have defined something like this:

```
.button-wrapper div {
            background: transparent;
            border: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 4px 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            font-family:Impact;
        font-size:26px;
        font-weight:normal;
        text-align: center;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #000000;
            -webkit-transform: skewX(-35deg);
            -moz-transform: skewX(-35deg);
            -o-transform: skewX(-35deg);
            transform: skewX(-35deg);
}
```

where button-wrapper is the button that i've skewed. The issue is that if I use other divs the unskewing continues and i have the elements inside the button hang on the other side. Any idea to how i can get what i want. Here's what I've tried for html:

```
  <div class="button-wrapper" href="sport.php">
      <div id="inner_text">
          <img src="images/icon.gif" width="40px" height="40px">
          <span width="200px">  sometext </span>
          <img src="images/light.gif" width="40px" height="40px">
      </div>
  </div>
```

UPDATE: here's the image
[image: image of what i want]

Comment: An image with what you want to achieve would be really helpful.

Comment: Agreed, an image here is the key to understanding the structure that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have to specify no skewX values on the inner items to avoid them inheriting the CSS from the container.